# youtube Integration on a settop box and questions

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

We are trying to integrate Youtube app on a STB that is using RDK middleware (capable of running HTML5/javascript applications). I have been through the "YouTube TV HTML5 Technical Requirements 2016" document and have some questions.

1) As per my understanding youtube is an opensource app and integration work will be required? Will there be any customization be required? For example there is a difference how search functionality is available on different device types. Youtube app being run on a browser on a PC, a textbox is available where you can type what you want to search and then press the search icon next to it to start the search. However on the devices like Smart TV, Set Top Box where user does not have the pointing device and the keyboard, usually soft keyboard is required to be shown on the screen and search starts automatically after entering certain number of characters. I want to know if this functionality is customized by the app integrator or there are different code bases for different device types?

Similar questions i have is for the settings menu. For example to support dial 2.0 protocol to remotely launch the youtube application from the remote device you need to have settings menu to let you to pair / unpair the device. So settings menu seems to be different for different device types.

2) Similarly there are differences how user is allowed to perform forward / rewind during the playback. On PC browser i have seen user can seek to any position with in a stream using a mouse. However on smart TV's there is a rewind  forward button which result in seek -/+ 10 secs. I have not seen trick modes on any implementation. Are trick modes required and how they are performed? If they are required then using seek or some sort of iframe tag file to allow smooth trickmodes? Again doesn't that part come from the app itself?

3) I'm trying to find if Youtube support any or all of these MPEG-DASH, Apple HLS, Microsoft Smooth Streaming, adaptive bit rate protocols. However not having much luck with them. I tried to capture the packets using wireshark and launched the youtube application and played back the video but i was unable to see any http calls that can give me hint that youtube app is using any of the above ABR formats (may be all the communication was under TLS and so encrypted and so i was unable to find whats going on). Even youtube app running from a browser on a PC, when i playback the video, i can see under settings -> Quality always remain at auto, 480p for the whole duration of playback. And if i change the quality to any value e.g 720p it always stay there for the whole duration of the playback. This is telling me it is not using any of the ABR formats. So i guess these ABR formats are probably for future use?

4) Under the youtube specifications i can see that target device must implement at least com.youtube.playready and com.widevine.alpha (for 4K contents) DRM's. I was trying to find if you tube has any content available in these formats but was unable to find any. Can you please confirm?

I would appreciate if someone can answer these or point me in the right direction.

Best Regards,
Farhan

Comment: What code you have tried?

Comment: Also are there any youtube videos having multiple audio tracks and you tube app allows track selection?